# Converting string to dictionary with url in the string

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following string:

```
  setti = "{PolInt:-1,comp:true,custh:true,script:test123.py,date1:2020-01-01,date2:2021-01-31,list:['@qwe'],clist:-123,url:https://example.excapmle.com/login/api/odata/qwetest(p=['@qwe'],date1=2000-05-01,date2=2001-12-31,c=-4),c12:qweq213-eqwas123}"
```

I am trying to convert this string to a dictionary and the following tries have failed:

```
setti = json.dumps(setti)
setti = literal_eval(setti)
```

This fails as it doesn't recognize the `(` in the string and `json.loads` fails as well. Is there an easy to way to achieve this?

Comment: Where is `setti` coming from?  It's not a valid JSON string.  Can it be generated as a valid JSON string?

Comment: @RocketHazmat It cannot be generated as a valid JSON string. It's coming from a different application.

Comment: I guess you can't edit the output of this specific application?  There's no option to have said application give you a better output?  As shown, you'll probably need to manually parse this into an object.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I can manually make changes to this string but yeah, no control to the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mentioned, the string you provided doesn't contain a valid JSON object so `json.loads()` won't work. One alternative is to extract the data using RegEx, for example:

```
setti_dict = {} 

for x, y in re.findall("{?([^:]+):([^:]+|.+\))[,}]", setti):
    setti_dict[x] = y
```